# How to make Collection View with resizeable cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I would like to create a UICollectionView that would show 2x2 grid of photos within cells. When the cell is tapped by the user, the collection view should resize the cell to fill an entire collection view (preferably with a zoom-in animation) and behave like the table view. When the user taps on the full screen cell, it should take him to the detail view. When the user does the pinch gesture, the collection view should "zoom out" to the 2x2 grid.

[image: Graphical description of the problem]

The problem is that I don't know where to start with creating a collection view that would provide me the desired results. Should I start with creating the smaller cells, and then resizing them in code, or should I start with the big cell? Finally, is there a better solution for the problem?

Any your help would be greately appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Take a look at UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/index.html, excellent tutorial here as well: http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/

Comment: if you need to be able to scroll between larger views, you probably need to change the collection view layout. You can check http://www.objc.io/issue-12/collectionview-animations.html this link, section "Transitions Between UICollectionViewController Instances". Hope it helps

Comment: I'll check your links out, thanks for help!

Comment: @marvin that link was very useful for me, thanks! The only problem I have encountered is that when I try to set the collection view cell's size programatically with '- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}' it doesn't affect the view I want it to, but it affects the other one (even though it is implemented in the correct class)

Comment: I also tried the UICollectionFlowLayout for setting the cell's size, and it still shrinks to the size set in the simulator. Is there any way to override it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method ,Add UIImageview into the view,like this.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UIImageView *imageview=[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[self.view addSubview:imageview];
```

Then Add **Tap Gesture Recognizer on UIImageview** and  **present the DetailView**.

.This link can helpfull [Github Photo Album](https://github.com/divyeshdobariya/Photo-Album)

Hope this is helpfull.

Comment: Thanks for help with that! I'll try to post my solution here regarding detail view and cell resizing when I'm finished with coding.